# Chaining nullable blocks in Objective-C and in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks, chaining, swift-block

I need to have a possibility to write:

```
//if someCase1
block1(block2(block3()))
//if someCase2
block1(block3())
//if someCase3
block2(block3())
```

where blocks are some blocks of code. I saw a lot of examples but no one describes how to declare chaining and nullable blocks simultaneously (it seems `nullable` is required for this case).

How to solve this issue? Both Swift and Objective-C solutions are applicable.

Comment: Do you need to implement reactive programming? You should look at [`ReactiveCocoa`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa) or something then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Swift**, you can achieve this using **`closures`**.

Create 3 `variables` of type `(()->())` namely - `block1, block2, block3`

1. Call `block2` inside `block1`
2. Call `block3` inside `block2`

**Example:**

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("All blocks executed")
}

dispatchGroup.enter()
let block3 = {
    print("block3 called")
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}

dispatchGroup.enter()
let block2 = {
    print("block2 called")
    block3()
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}

dispatchGroup.enter()
let block1 = {
    print("block1 called")
    block2()
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}

block1()
```

In the above code, I've used `DispatchGroup` for `synchronous` execution of all the `blocks`.

Comment: not applicable because `block2` and `block3` may have asynchronous completion

Comment: So you don't want asynchronous handling for the blocks?

Comment: the problem is I have 3 bool cases and I should skip some blocks according to these cases. The previous programmer duplicated code inside blocks to define all the possible cases